# Would it be incorrect to not include 儿 here?

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice, characters, pronunciation

For example, what's the difference between 那边儿 and 那边? When writing in Chinese do I need the 儿 because I've heard people say both.

Comment: You shouldn't, it's dialectal in most instances. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhua

Comment: It's up to you, but in writing this is redundant, unless you explicitly want to emphasize this or are proud of your Beijing accent. Better omit 儿 where you can, it does not add any meaning, just one more character to type or write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

儿 is Pekingese (beijing dialect), like "lah" in singlish (singapore english).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_dialect

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singlish#Lah

in general, you don't need to write it; unless you want to impress readers that it's pekingese.

Comment: what if I'm saying  他在那儿 or 他在这儿? Is the 儿 still necessary?

Comment: if it's "as suffix" (綴), not necessary, have a look 國語辭典:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000010486

Comment: @ChrisG  那儿 and 这儿 can be and usually are written as 那里 and 这里, so you can drop the 儿. The only cases where 儿 is not negotiable are 女儿，儿子, 婴儿, etc. i.e. where 儿 is used in it's original meaning (son, child).

Comment: I was told today that 一会儿 needs the 儿  but I've heard people saying it without the 儿 ?

Comment: 「一會兒」也作「會子」、「會兒」、「一會」、「一會子」。
i would say that 兒 is not a must in this situation.

國語辭典: http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000149349

Comment: After showing my teacher your links, she responded that these websites are based on classical Chinese and that in modern Chinese, the 儿 becomes necessary in writing a lot of words like 一会儿 and even in 一会儿子。

Answer (score 0):

Well 儿 can appear in formal language. We Chinese speakers don't really care so much. Actually it can mean something different with or without 儿 in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

when you writing an essays or something like that, or in a informal communication(daily chat) you can use “儿” as you like ,but in some formal case, especially writing documents,you'd better not use it,